# Is Puppet On Topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I'm self-training on `puppet` and interested in writing up some Puppet-related topics in Q&A format for questions that took me a while to answer because I wasn't able to find a decent resource online.

Since `puppet` is multiplatform (even with [Windows support](http://info.puppetlabs.com/what-windows-admins-need-from-configuration-management.html)) would it still be considered on-topic for this SE or would I need to post those over on ServerFault?

Comment: Excellent. I'm looking forward to these questions!

Comment: Some context: [Puppet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29) - *Puppet is an open source configuration management utility. It runs on many Unix-like systems as well as on Microsoft Windows, and includes its own declarative language to describe system configuration.*.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, absolutely. As long as something works on *nix, it's on topic. Whether it works on other systems as well or not is irrelevant.

If your questions are about using software X on a *nix platform, they are welcome here. If they are platform agnostic, Super User might be a better place for them.

Comment: How do you mean "platform agnostic"? Most of the puppet stuff I would want to post is going to be applicable to most *nix platforms.

Comment: I mean that if your Q&As are equally applicable to *nix and Windows, they'd still be on topic but would probably be more so on [su]. If they are about using puppet on a nix platform, they are perfect for us.

Comment: Though puppet is platform agnostic, the use of puppet for specific *nix system configuration seems even more appropriate for unix.SE, but may also be appropriate for ServerFault.

Answer (score 11):

While such questions may be acceptable on Unix.SE, DevOps type questions are more at home on ServerFault. They currently have [1,175 questions tagged `puppet`](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/puppet).

Comment: Interesting; there's only slightly more (1,420) [questions tagged puppet on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/puppet). I would have thought there'd be much more.

Comment: There's a difference between writing puppet manifests and managing the puppet infrastructure and I'd guess that the first gets mostly to Unix.SE and the latter goes to ServerFault.